# What is being recorded in this Latin church vital record?

Tags: 18th-century, palaeography, church-records, latin, slovenia

I have a document from the Ljubljana archives in Slovenia that I do not understand:

[image]

As best I can tell, it is written in Latin and there are alternating columns for male and female sex.  I think a date and house number are in the first column.  Is this some kind of baptism record?  I think I'm most interested in the * entry with numeral 8:

[image]

Which appears to read:

```
8 Mathias, Andreas Lousheg ejurgue
  vxoais gealaudis Vedmayerin fil
  Lagid: Sub Ino Ashiber, Bsarhiealus
  erl 13 January 1771 per N. R. I.
  Malhiam Mervezh Cogreral: Baboini
  Anton Kovalshekshiel Glhorina Sebastian
    Ex Hoarbauza
```

What kind of record is this?  Baptism, marriage, death, status animarum, or something else?  Why does it have this unusual organization that is new to me?

I think it might be a baptism record for Andre or Mathias Gregortschitsch with parents Sebastian Gregortschitsch and Gertrud Gotschitinn who live in Rosenberg 1 of Šentrupert.

Comment: How did you come by this record? Do you have the archives' catalog entry fr it?

Comment: It was included in transcriptions the archives provided, but for this page, no explanation was given.

Answer (score 9):

*Mathias, Andreæ [Kousheg?] ejusque uxoris gertrudis [Vidmagesin?], fil. legit. sub Dno [Ashiber?], baptizatus est 13 Januarÿ 1771 per M. ?. D. Mathiam [Mervezh?] cooperat. Patrini Anton Kovatschetski et Catharina Schirzlin ex [Hvartouza?].*

Matthew, legitimate son of Andrew [Kousheg] and his wife Gertrude [Vidmages], was baptized in district [Ashiber] on January 13 1771 by assistant pastor Matthew [Marvezh]. Godparents Anthony Kovatschetski and Catherine Schirzl from [Hvartouza].

---

I've put square brackets around the things (mostly surnames) that I'm particularly unsure of. I'm fairly certain that:

- Mathias is the child
- Andreas K-something is his father
- his mother is Gertrude V-something with a German-style feminine
  ending on her surname
- Dno is an abbreviation for an oblique case of some word related to *dominus* "lord"; it appears in other entries on the page as something like *dominio*, and is clearly a geopolitical designation of some type
- the words before the date are "was baptized"
- the name after the date is the officiant and his position (if I
  recall correctly, *cooperator* is something roughly along the lines
  of assistant pastor)
- Anton and Catharina are the godparents, and Catharina's surname has the German feminine ending
- the H-something at the end is the name of the place that they come from.

The first column's header is "number of the house where the birth occurred".

Comment: Surname is likely Kavšek aka Kauschek or something that phonetically sounds like that, so rather than Kousheg, Kauschek or something like that.

Comment: Could the baptism location be: [Hrastovica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hrastovica,_Mokronog-Trebelno)?

Comment: @WilliamKF, the father's surname is definitely written here with a -g, but in many German accents, final consonants are automatically devoiced, so whatever the actual letters being used, I think they meant a name that sounds like [kʌʊʃɛk] (or thereabouts).

Comment: I haven't tracked down a Slovenian gazetteer to check: did Hrastovica have a German name? My fairly-confident-parts reading of H_art__za doesn't quite fit the Slovenian, but 'z' does mean the /ts/ sound in German, which is what I believe 'c' means in Slovenian (same as in Hungarian).

Comment: I don't know if there was/is a German name for Hrastovica, but hrastov means oak and -ica is a diminutive, so literally meaning "little oak".

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation is:

> 8 [Numerus domus in qua nata proles] Mathias, Andrea Kousheg ejusque
>   uxoris gertrudis Vidmayerin, fil. legit. [filius legitimus] sub Dno
>   [Dominio] Ashiber, baptizatus est 13 Januarius 1771 per M.R.D. [M.
>   Reverendus Dominus] Mathiam Mervezh cooperat. [cooperator] Patrini Anton
>   Kovatshetski et Catharina Schirzlin ex Hrastovza.

8 [Number of the house where the child was born] Matthew, legitimate son of Andrew Kousheg and his wife Gertrude Vidmayer, was baptized under landowner Ashiber on January 13 1771 by Reverend Sir chaplain Matthew Marvezh. Godparents [were] Anthony Kovatshetski and Catherine Schirzl from Hrastovza.

I don't know what the "M" means in M.R.D. R.D. means reverendus dominus or Reverend Sir. I have seen A.R.D. which means admodum reverendus dominus or something like Most Reverend Sir.